# Sharpen or fix blurred logo in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, logo

Good day! I was told to fix a department logo from blurred to hd. Unfortunately I am not that good at restoration. How do you sharpen such images? Tried sharpen smart tool from other tutorials but very unsuccessful. Thanks for the help.

[image]

Comment: You would need to recreate this from scratch to be effective.

Comment: It's just easier to recreate (at least part of) this instead. Text and the green curves / blue part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Photoshop's sharpen creates something like this:

[image]

There's some sharpening done, but the result is far from fine. Sharpening algorithms cannot know what the original was, they work separately every pixel without knowing the whole. You can make an automatic image trace to vector. The result will be different, but not better due the inability to see the whole. I mean a human can guess how it was constructed, Photoshop, Illustrator etc. programs cannot.

The only way to a good result is to redraw it. A skilled Illustrator(or other vector drawing program) user could do it in a couple of hours.

Before redrawing one must decide the right forms, colors, used font, edge strokes i.e. what there actually should exist. To avoid conflicts it's useful to negotiate at first what there exists and make an annotated paper copy of the result. For ex should the light wavy jigsaw puzzle style ornament on the green part be solid white or what?

If you cannot draw things like this, get pro help.

Comment: How about the text? Is it possible to retrieve it and be enhanced? Thanks.

Comment: Write a new text. You must decide the right font. Font identifiers such as FontSquirrel or Whatisthefont can help, but the decision is yours. I guess R or S or both are actually "logotype" writings i.e. the text is converted to curves and the result is edited more or less with curve editing tools.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps:

- Firstly open your company’s logo in Photoshop.
- Duplicate the background layer by pressing Ctrl + J. Make sure you
  must be on layer 1.
- Next, go to the filter option and choose High Pass. Your logo will
  become sharper as you set the higher value.

Answer (score -3):

This logo has to be redesigned as vector in Illustrator. Sharpening in Photoshop won't work. I can help you/ guide you with AI file.

Comment: This is an old question and it's specific about Photoshop. Check [answer] to learn more about the site.